# 2 Alerts conditions in Script but only 1 can be selected

Tags: pine-script, alert, pine-script-v5

I have added 2 conditions in the script, one alert should fire when SMA crosses the other SMA upwards, to other alert when the SMA cross the other SMA downwards.
This is the script:

```
//@version=5
indicator('SMMA 5-13 cross', shorttitle='SMMA 5-13 Cross', overlay=true, max_bars_back=501)

len1 = input.int(5, minval=1, title='Length')
src1 = input(close, title='Source')
smma1 = 0.0
sma_1 = ta.sma(src1, len1)
smma1 := na(smma1[1]) ? sma_1 : (smma1[1] * (len1 - 1) + src1) / len1
plot(smma1, color=color.new(color.lime, 0), linewidth=3)
timeInput = input('0830-1600', title="Indicator will work during following time (has to be according to the exchange's timezone):")
t = time(timeframe.period, timeInput)

len2 = input.int(13, minval=1, title='Length')
src2 = input(close, title='Source')
smma2 = 0.0
sma_2 = ta.sma(src2, len2)
smma2 := na(smma2[1]) ? sma_2 : (smma2[1] * (len2 - 1) + src2) / len2
plot(smma2, color=color.new(color.red, 0), linewidth=3)
//Kreise zeichen , Zeit After und Premarket exkludieren

MyCondition =  ta.crossover(smma2, smma1) and t
plot(ta.crossover(smma1, smma2) and t ? smma1 : na, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=10, color=color.new(color.green, 50)) 
if MyCondition
    alert( "SMMA Cross Long", alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)

MyCondition2 =  ta.crossunder(smma1, smma2) and t
plot(ta.crossunder(smma1, smma2) and t ? smma1 : na, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=10, color=color.new(color.red, 50)) 
if MyCondition2
    alert( "SMMA Cross Short", alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
```

In the alert menu, I can only chose one Alert and it fires 2 alerts, once a SMA crosses another.
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing nothing wrong. When you use `alert()`, you won't have an option for each call like you have with `alertcondition()`.

You need to add an `input.bool()` for your alerts so you can enable/disable them from the inputs section.

```
enable_alert1 = input.bool(false, "Enable alert 1?")
enable_alert2 = input.bool(false, "Enable alert 2?")

if MyCondition and enable_alert1
    alert( "SMMA Cross Long", alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)

if MyCondition2 and enable_alert2
    alert( "SMMA Cross Short", alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
```